# Charging 2 LiPos in serial used as split rail

Tags: batteries, charging, lipo

I was wondering what the recommendations are for creating a charging circuit for 2 LiPos when they are connected in series, but as a split rail, shown below.

[image: 2 LiPos connected in series, as split rail]

Currently I am just disconnecting them and charging them using the sparkfun charger PRT-10217. Previously I have implemented a charging circuit around the MCP73831 for a single LiPo, so I was wondering if it were possible to use two of those in this type of configuration:
[image: Two MCP73831]

This is of course assuming that I disconnect the batteries from the rest of the circuit first!

Is there anything else I need to be careful of? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since lipos can be very dangerous, and 'assuming that I disconnect the batteries from the rest of the circuit first' doesn't lend much confidence, I advise you **make it as fool-proof as possible**.

Adafruit has a decent article on [multi-cell charging](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-cell-lipo-charging/overview?view=all), of which I'll reproduce here.  Basically, you'll want a 3PDT switch (not abundant, but available) to switch between connecting the batteries to the load and to the chargers.

[image: Fast charging two lipos]

Otherwise, you could just remove the batteries from the circuit and charge them.  Whichever method you choose, again, I advise not to assume that the operator (you or another user) remembers to hit a switch in order to avoid a potentially unsafe state of the batteries.

Comment: I'd recommend against paralleling them as in your second circuit: if they're not equally charged, dangerous current could flow.

Comment: @AbeKarplus Good call -- I removed it from my answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I was a bit more blasé about that then I meant to be. That seems a good way to go. Its probably a good idea to also add some logic to the LED indicators so they only show when both cells are fully charged. Thanks

Comment: @Jimbles You never can tell what someone's thought of on the Interwebs :)  And yes, I'd take full advantage of that STAT pin: you could put one LED on there (VDD to STAT) for charging and one (STAT to GND) for complete.  Or just one for charging with the MCP73832.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the balance wires together. Both wires have to be the same type of lithium polymer battery with the same mA-Hours. They use two 2200 mA-H or 2s lithium polymer batteries and connect the balance wires